# Eclipse Code Completion: Is it possible to select a method without the parameters?

Tags: java, eclipse

The code completion in Eclipse offers the available methods for an object. For a string object I could select this, for example:

`lastIndexOf(str, fromIndex)`.

Is it somehow possible to get only the method `lastIndexOf` without the parameters `(str, fromIndex)`?

Comment: How will that help ? Whats the use case ?

Comment: This link should help you: http://blog.deepakazad.com/2012/06/jdt-tip-toggle-between-inserting-and.html

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html is the general tips/tricks for eclipse .. But couldn't find a matchingsolution for your question ,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Preferences go to: Java->Editor->Content Assist. In the Insertion section uncheck the "Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments" option. After this you will get the method name and the parenthesis after it, no parameters.

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: My question is answered, thank you for your support. It looks like you can only enable or disable this behaviour completely. It would be just nice to have this feature on request, for example hitting ENTER takes over the complete highlighted method including the parameters, hitting STRG + ENTER takes over only the method with empty parenthesis. But this is up to the developers of Eclipse, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question.

Maybe it helps to understand that a method is more than just its name. A method is distinguished by its method-signature which is in your case `lastIndexOf(String, int)`.

Somewhere in the String-class this very method is defined as `lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` and eclipse just looks up that definition and hands it to you. Probably the guy who wrote that method had something in mind as he declared the String as `str` and the int as `fromIndex`.

Comment: While what you say is true, I can imagine a person just wanting to not-autocomplete those things from the definition. Preferences differ, and if you find that those things clutter or confuse your work, it's a valid question to try and find out if you can get auto-complete that doesn't insert those things?

Comment: It is a perfectly valid question. But I should add that what the user asks for may is not what he wants. I imagine here that his naming differs for some params and he gets annoyed. I am not using eclipse for some time now, but wasn't it about 'cursor-down' and 'enter'?